# chromedriver has stopped working

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm totally new to selenium and when I wrote this piece of code, I'm getting an error from chrome saying "chrome driver has stopped working" and it asks me to close chrome or not.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path="C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

After I execute this line in my IDLE

> driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

Chrome opens but says "You are using unsupported command line flag: -- ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer." and it pops up a dialog box telling me to "Disable developer mode extensions"

After I type this line

> driver.get("https://www.google.com")

A dialog box appears saying chromedriver.exe has stopped working and it gives me a button to close program. Sometimes this doesn't appear straight away, I get some error on IDLE GUI like this. [Click me for the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDcPt.jpg)

Few details :-

Chrome Version :- 60.0.3112.101

chromedriver version :- 2.9.248315

Python version :- 2.7.13

Comment: You should [upgrade your chromedriver to 2.31](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.31/)...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Thanks a lot mate, that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade to the newest chromedriver version.
[Link to chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)